# Was the book "A Dog of Flanders" less popular in Western countries than in Japan?

Tags: a-dog-of-flanders, ouida

The book *[A Dog of Flanders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Dog_of_Flanders)* is popular in Japan and known as a very sad story. However, I heard that this story is about a loser and isn't very popular in Western countries. Is this true that it's less popular in Western countries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer does not attempt to judge the book's popularity in Western countries in general, but in Flanders, where the story is set, and where I come from. (Antwerp is in Flanders.)

The novel was published in English in 1872 by Marie Louise de la Ramée (using the pseudonym Ouida). I never heard of her while studying English literature at university. The first time I heard about the story was through the comic strip adaptation in the Belgian/Flemish series [Suske en Wiske](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spike_and_Suzy), in an album named [Het dreigende dinges](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Het_dreigende_dinges) (Dutch for "the threatening thing"; Willy Vandersteen, who invented the series, liked alliterations in titles). It was only after the publication of this comic strip that *A Dog of Flanders* was translated into Dutch (in 1987). ("Suske en Wiske" is one of the most popular comic strip series in Flanders; you could not grow up in Flanders after the 1950s without knowing Suske en Wiske.)

After this, you could still come across articles such as ["Vlaanderen en Antwerpen ontdekken na meer dan honderd jaar hun geheime ambassadeur in Japan en Korea : een hond van Vlaanderen"](http://zoeken.gent.bibliotheek.be/detail/Jan-Corteel/Vlaanderen-en-Antwerpen-ontdekken-na-meer-dan/Artikel-uit-tijdschrift/?itemid=%7Clibrary%2Fmarc%2Fvlacc%7C1254313) (sorry, just a library catalogue entry). The title means "After more than 100 years Flanders and Antwerp discover their secret ambassador in Japan and Korea: a dog of Flanders"; the title implicitly suggests the relative obscurity of the story in Flanders in the early 1990s. I think the story is still quite obscure for people who haven't read the Suske en Wiske comic.

**Update**: There is a [French translation](https://www.amazon.fr/Chien-Flandres-Traduit-conte-No%C3%ABl-ebook/dp/B06XVDFS2X/) of the book (possibly self published by the translator) but I have not been able to find a German or a Spanish translation.